# wordpress divi & profitbuilder both used in a website

Tags: wordpress

Before,this form allowed me to fully edit user submitted content (image, text and link). Now, it seems I cannot move the “URL” or image to better format the page

as see the  first image of wp-contact form

[image]

after submitting the form wee cannot move or edit the image and url link as you see in below image

[image]

can anyone help me out for this problem ..!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Any errors displayed and how do you submit the page?

Comment: no error has come , when we submit the form  after submitting form ,when we edit the post the the url and image have no options to edit while the description area have editing option thorigh  divi editor

Comment: no error display but if we edit the post in profit-builder then the Divi editor contents are deleted or same as if we edit the post in Divi editor the profit-builder date deleted.